Is momentum expectation value always 0 for an eigenfunction?
in which cases the following derivation holds?
assume the Hamiltonian
$$H = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \hat{V}(r)$$
now
$$[\hat{r},H] = -i\hbar \hat{p} \ \text{and}\ 
\langle\phi|\hat{p}|\phi\rangle \propto \langle\phi|[\hat{r},H]|\phi\rangle = (E-E) \cdot \langle\phi|\hat{r}|\phi\rangle = 0$$
but if we take the $\hat{V}=0$ (free Hamiltonian)
for example $|\phi\rangle = \frac{e^{ikr}}{\sqrt{V}}$
will give
$$P|\phi\rangle = \hbar k\frac{e^{ikr}}{\sqrt{V}} \Rightarrow \langle P\rangle = \hbar k$$
and $$H|\phi\rangle = \frac{(\hbar k)^2}{2m}\frac{e^{ikr}}{\sqrt{V}} \Rightarrow E = \frac{(\hbar k)^2}{2m}$$
I read in another post that this is because the eigenvalues of $p$ are non-normalizable (even though I don't see a problem if I contain space in a finite volume $V$).
the whole thing seems a bit weird to me - so besides asking when this derivation holds, i would love to hear about some implications of it

Wecome to the world of quantum operator paradoxes!
The resolution to your $\langle \psi|\hat p|\psi\rangle=0$ paradox is partly as you say: When the system is infinite the states $|p\rangle$ are not normalizable and so the manipulations are invalid.
In particlular you have $E-E=0$, while $\langle p|\hat r|p\rangle=\infty$, so the product is ill defined.
If you have a finite size system with periodic boundary conditions then you can have $\langle \psi|\hat p|\psi\rangle$ being non zero, but you cannot use $-i\hbar \hat p= [\hat r, H]$ because $\hat r$ is not a well-defined operator --- you have to identitfy $\hat r$ with $\hat r+L$ so the best you can do for a position operator is $\exp\{2\pi in\hat r/L\}$. If you have $\psi(0)=\Psi(L)=0$ boundary conditions then $\hat p$  is not an observable as it has no eigenvectors.  Somthing like this will happen for any Boundary conditions that make $H$ self-adjoint.

I should add that the expectation of $\hat p$ is zero for for discrete-spectrum bound states in which   $\langle \psi|\hat r|\psi\rangle$ is finiite   ---  the proof being that given in the oriinal question.

I don't think the periodic position operator should depend on $n$; the discretization happens in momentum space, so $\hat{x}_L$ is still continuous. Maybe a good definition would be
$$
\hat{x}_L=\frac{L}{2\pi}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{L}\hat{x}\right) \ .
$$
This is hermitian, and $\hat{x}_L\rightarrow\hat{x}$ in the infinite space limit; no ambiguity with $n/L$ as $L\rightarrow\infty$.

The result holds a little more generally whenever $\psi(x)$ is real and $\hat p$ is self-adjoint; $\psi(x)$ need be a an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian i.e. you do not need to assume $H\vert\psi\rangle=E\vert\psi\rangle$ for real $E$.
This is easy to see since
\begin{align}
\langle \psi\vert \hat p\vert\psi\rangle&=\int dx \psi (x) (-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx})\psi(x)\\
&=-i\left[ \hbar \int dx \psi (x) (\frac{d}{dx})\psi(x) \right]
\end{align}
since $\psi(x)$ is real.  Now,
$$
\left[ \hbar \int dx \psi (x) (\frac{d}{dx})\psi(x) \right]  \tag{1}
$$
is clearly real since it is an integral of a real integrand.  This means in turn that $\langle\psi\vert \hat p\vert\psi\rangle$ would be purely imaginary if Eq.(1) were non-zero.  However the average value of a self-adjoint operator must be real so therefore the only possibility is that Eq.(1) is $0$.
For bound state in 1d, it is always possible to choose the eigenstates to be real so the special case of $\psi_n(x)$ follows. This also relies on having $\hat p$ to be self-adjoint.  Plane waves are not bound state and there are cases where $\hat p$ is not necessarily self adjoint (as discussed in another answer and elsewhere on this site).
Note also that, if you put in the time dependence on $\Psi(x,t)$, the wavefunction $\Psi(x,t)$ is no longer necessarily real, especially is $\psi(x)$ is a sum of eigenstates with different energies; in other words, (1) is no longer necessarily the integral of a real function.  Then of course you can have $\langle p\rangle\ne 0$ since the assumption of real function fails.
